# Can I run a Shiny app from within R Tools for Visual Studio

Tags: r, visual-studio, shiny, rtvs

Is it possible to run Shiny apps from within Visual Studio if I'm using *R Tools for Visual Studio (RTVS)*.  If yes, how?

Comment: You can run shiny apps from anywhere R runs. That doesn't necessarily mean it will be hard-coded into the application. Rather, it will open up in your default browser. See the vignette on how to run a shiny app.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I was hoping someone would know a nice point-and-click way to do it instead of running the `runApp` line of code every time.

Comment: Perhaps the team is accepting feature requests (assuming it doesn't exist yet).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I thought there wasn't, but as it turns out, there *is* a "Run Shiny App" button in RTVS!

[image]

Comment: get: Error in shinyAppDir(x) : App dir must contain either app.R or server.R. Any idea?

Comment: That's because VS does not know there the App is. Give it the address of the folder that contains both ui.R and server.R files, such as "appDir = C:/Users/myShiny", then run "runApp(appDir)", the ShinyApp will run properly.

Comment: hi, i installed RTVS but can't find the button, any idea why?