# How to use Shiny app in my own C# Wep App

Tags: c#, r, shiny

I have created A Shiny App And i want to insert the same content of my shinyapp app in my C# Application. If there's any way to do that ?

Comment: use the iframe.

Comment: This will provide R Code also to be used in C# ?

Comment: and with this method ShinyApp will still in the same server not in my own one, I'm Seeking to find any way to apply my R Cod in my C# Wep App

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it, this is how I set it up for my team, so we can have the best of both worlds is to use an `iframe`. If you're using `MVC` then something like this should do:

**Controller.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Dashboard.Controllers
{
    public class ShinyController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.IFrameSrc = "Address to your shiny app";
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<iframe style="border: 0; position:relative; width:100%; height:100%" src="@ViewBag.IFrameSrc"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks Pork For this Answer But there's no way to use the code only without making shiny app on the server and then use the link of this app in server ? I mean can i use shinyapp code in R studio in C# code in Visual Studio directly ?

Comment: You can maybe try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45605523/can-i-run-a-shiny-app-from-within-r-tools-for-visual-studio

Comment: But This one for using RTools not to use R Code in C#

Comment: You could use something like R.NET:  https://github.com/rdotnet/rdotnet